# How to : Use Animations.css after Clicking a button

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

I want to Use animations.css file animations run after i click a button,  function to write the `class` name but it didn't work

I have linked the Style sheet: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.0/animate.min.css" />` and added button`<button class="btnForAnimation" onclick="myAniFunction">Click</button>`+ Jquery but no use .

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset='utf8'>
<head>
<h1 class="animate__animated animate__bounceInLeft">An animated element</h1><--!animation occured when onload-->
<button onclick=myfunction >Click me</button>
<--!Also Include code.jquery.com's v4.1.1 jquery code lib-->
<script lang....>
function myAnifunction() { /* code for loading stylesheet but it will took long*/}
</script>

</head>
</html>
```

Now I want that when I click the button the animation occurs

I can use directly animations but I only want to use the library.

Comment: Can you show the javascript/jquery code you tried running, or provide a better explanation as to what you are trying to achieve exactly when the button is pressed?

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your source code it is very hard to tell what you've done wrong. However, I can tell you that `Document.write` is [not used for setting class names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write). Instead, you should be using the [Element.classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) API.

Below is a working example of what you are trying to accomplish. I've opted *not* to use jQuery for this example because, for someone such as yourself who is just starting out in web development, you should focus on learning the ins and outs of vanilla JavaScript long before dealing with libraries and frameworks.

If you have any questions about the implementation, feel free to ask them in the comments below.

```js
// Select the h1 element from the DOM
const h1 = document.querySelector('h1')

// Select the first button element from
// the DOM with a class of 'btn'
const btn = document.querySelector('.btn')

// Listen to the click event.
// This is very similar to how you used "onclick=myfunction" but
// is grenerally considered the "better" way to do it for a number
// of reasons that are outside the scope of this question.
btn.addEventListener('click', function () {
   // Remove the bounce class, if it exists.
   h1.classList.remove('animate__bounceInLeft')
   
   // Force the browser to recalculate the page styles
   // because style updates are typically batched.
   // Otherwise, it be like nothing happened because
   // we're removing the class and then immediately adding
   // it again.
   h1.offsetWidth
   
   // Finally, add the bounce class so the heading animates.
   // If you only want the heading to animate the first time
   // the button is clicked, and do nothing from then out, this
   // is the only line that is needed in this function.
   h1.classList.add('animate__bounceInLeft')
})
```

```css
/* Styles for presentation only */

body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.btn {
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.0/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<!--
 Your question suggests that you didn't
 want this to animate when the page loads.
 As such, I've removed the `animate__bounceInLeft` class
 which effectively removes the animation until we add it later
 with JavaScript.
 
 If I misunderstood you, simply add the class back and everything will continue to work.
-->
<h1 class="animate__animated">An animated element</h1>

<button class="btn">Click</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are new to web development, I understand.
Here, the problem is when you add the class initially, it just adds up to your selected element as soon as page loads.
Solution is You need to add the class only when you click the button. As I could see, you also added a function.

```
<h1 class="animate__animated">An animated element</h1>
<button onclick=myfunction()>Click me</button>
```

As you could see, I removed that class. Now in function,

```
function myfunction(){
     const elementToAnimate = document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0];
     elementToAnimate.classList.add('animate__bounceInLeft');
}
```

1. I selected your element, on which you choose to add class,
2. Then, With help of classList, I added the class.

[Here is the working example.](https://jsfiddle.net/vikasguptaa9/w10p8vm7/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Ummm, well, the best way I can think of is to ***not*** give the `animate__animated animate__bounceInLeft` class by default.

Then, as the next step, add the following JavaScript:

```
const btn = document.getElementByTagName("button");

btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
document.querySelector('h1').classList.add('animate__animated animate__bounceInLeft');
})
```

This will add the `animate__animated animate__bounceInLeft` class to the `h1` as soon as the button is clicked.

Now that the `h1` has the class names which animate it, the animation will occur.

---

I can see another error in your code, though not a serious one.

Your comment (in the code) has the following syntax:

```
<--!Also Include code.jquery.com's v4.1.1 jquery code lib-->
```

This is incorrect and invalid HTML. It should be:

```
<!--Also Include code.jquery.com's v4.1.1 jquery code lib-->
```

---

Hope I could help